# Blender can not detect my GPU

Tags: nvidia, cuda, blender

My blender preferences say, "No compatible GPUs found for path tracing, Cycles will render on CPU" for CUDA.

[image: Blender preferences]

Some relevant info:

- Blender version: Blender 2.82 (sub 7)
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9300H CPU @ 2.40GHz
- Ram: 8 GB

```
VGA compatible controller : NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

The following is the output of nvidia-smi command:

[image: Output of nvidia-smi command]

I am new to this forum. If something else is needed please inform me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Two proposed solutions:

#### Update Graphics Driver

Confirm that the graphics driver for your GPU is up-to-date.

#### Use the Proprietary NVIDIA Drivers

It appears to me that some users aren't able to use Blender with the Nouveau (open-source) driver for NVIDIA GPUs.

The solution may be to switch by using the official NVIDIA (proprietary) drivers instead.

> For Nvidia there are open source (Nouveau) and closed source (by Nvidia) graphics drivers. Blender functions best with the closed source drivers as they are more optimized and complete.
>
> — [Blender documentation for Linux - Nvidia Drivers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/gpu/linux/nvidia.html#drivers)

> There is an open source driver managed by a group of developers that are unrelated to NVIDIA, called Nouveau, and that driver doesn’t support Cuda.
>
> Cuda only works with the proprietary driver…
>
> — [NVIDIA forum - Can CUDA operate with open source Nvidia driver or only with Nvidia proprietary driver?](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/can-cuda-operate-with-open-source-nvidia-driver-or-only-with-nvidia-proprietary-driver/48039)

Ensure then when you try this, you're getting the latest version compatible with your GPU.

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt install nvidia-460
```

This installs what appears to be the latest drivers for the GTX 1650, may require a restart after installation.

Reference: [NVIDIA Driver Download: Linux x64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/170134/en-us)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it seems ubuntu had automatically installed nvidia driver version 460.32.03 in my machine during its installation. It can be seen in my nvidia-smi command output screenshot. So it should not be due to nouveau drivers, I think.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiSaha Ahh, my bad. Looking back at it, I saw Nouveau and just assumed you were using the Nouveau driver. Didn't read the "Kernal driver in use" properly, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

This did it in my case (Blender 3.4.1 on Kubuntu 23.04):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually not sure if this will work for you, but I experienced a similar issue with a GT 1030, and I had to set up CUDA on my computer with a handful of commands.

After hours of research on why none of my programs (Blender, Davinci Resolve, etc.) would work with my GPU (Or find it in the first place), I found a guide from Nvidia on how to get CUDA set up: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

While the guide wasn't the easiest thing to read, it pointed me in the right direction. I also restarted my computer after getting it all set up.

I'm assuming that this issue (No GPU found) is happening with multiple programs. If it's not, then this probably isn't the solution.

Sorry if this doesn't work, but I hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1194396)

Answer (score 0):

Just like The Data Architect answered, I had a similar issue and just needed to install nvidia cuda toolkit using "sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" and restart Blender.
This of course I assume is only for Nvidia cards.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen depending on how your software was installed. Snap installations are sandboxed for security.

For example, Ubuntu Studio's default installations for Blender & Firefox are not able to access external applications. So no CUDA, no video downloader co-app, etc.

Try uninstalling apps that have this issue & then reinstall them using the --classic flag to remove the snap sandbox restrictions.

```
sudo snap install blender --classic
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a couple of days trying to figure this out. I hope someone can use this to have an "Ah ha!" moment for the actual issue, but this is a workaround.

I am running UBUNTU Ubuntu 22.04 on a ASUS ProArt B550-creator motherboard with a AMD Ryzen 9 5950X, 64GB RAM and a Zotac Gaming Geforce RTX 3060, dual booting with Windows 11.

Blender in Windows 11 didn't have any issues. I could see the GPU in the CUDA tabs in *Preferences* -> *System*. Both the GPU and CPU showed up.

In Blender on Ubuntu, *Preferences* -> *System* under the *CUDA* tab, it showed only "No Compatible GPUs found for Cycles Requires NVIDIA GPU with a compute capability 3.0".

I reverted to an older version of Blender as was suggested by a post I found (downloaded it from the Blender website) and ran it from the command line, and the CUDA tab showed the GPU as expected.

And then, why not...

I downloaded the latest version of Blender as a tar file, untarred it, cd'ed into the created directory and started it from the command line as well, and the CUDA tab showed as expected.

I'm not sure why running it from the command line works, but the "apt" application install doesn't (even when it is started from the command line).

It looks like `apt install` installed Blender 3.0.1, and the download version that worked was for 3.4.1

I am going to try the [following post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331428/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-blender-in-ubuntu-instead-of-the-old-versi) next to see if it may be version related.

The following is a verbose history of the things I did to try and get it to work. I'm still not happy with it running from the command line, but at least I can use the GPU/Cycles with the latest version.

---

Installing blender via snap (later back this out):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blender -y
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Dealing with "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment" errors, referred to [ubuntu-drivers "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment" when installing nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436601/ubuntu-drivers-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-version-referenced-before-as)

```
ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py
sudo vi /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
sudo reboot
nvidia-smi
nvidia-setting
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo reboot
```

Removing `sudo apt install` version of Blender and installing it with `snap --classic` and reinstalling drivers, etc.

```
sudo snap remove blender
sudo apt remove blender
sudo snap install blender --classic
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
nvidia-smi
nvidia-settings
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Removing all  "Snap" version of blender and installing it with the normal apt install blender and reinstalling drivers, etc.

```
sudo snap remove blender
sudo apt install blender
nvidia-settings
nvidia-smi
```

Trying to run with some different drivers (testing blender after each block - no GPUs showed on any of the versions).

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
sudo reboot
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
nvidia-smi
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525
sudo reboot
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
sudo reboot
nvidia-settings
nvidia-smi
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-525
sudo reboot
nvidia-smi
```

I'm not sure this was needed, but I wanted to see if OpenGL was working (thinking it may have been related to missing drivers?) followed: http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-opengl-ubuntu-linux/

Installed VSCode:

```
code .
ls
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
g++ main.cpp -o firstOpenGlApp -lglut -lGLU -lGL
ls
./firstOpenGlApp
```

After reading a document that stated that if you have problems with the current Blender version your graphics card probably doesn't support the newer version of openGL (or something like that) and that you should install the 2.79 version

Downloaded 2.79 from https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/latest/

```
cd Downloads/
bunzip2 blender-2.79-e045fe53f1b0-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2
tar -xvf blender-2.79-e045fe53f1b0-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar 
cd blender-2.79-e045fe53f1b0-linux-glibc217-x86_64/
./blender
```

Downloaded 3.4.1 from https://www.blender.org/download/ by clicking the download button, and unzipping from the Files application by right-clicking on the file in the `~/Downloads/` directory and selecting *Extract here*.

```
cd blender-3.4.1-linux-x64/
./blender
```

Once the latest was started, the GPU shows as expected...  3.4.1 vs. 3.0.1 that was installed by `sudo apt install blender`

Comment: k, interesting enough.. After all of the above, i went back and installed blender with: "sudo snap install blender --classic" and it installed blender 3.4.1 and it works as expected.. So something that i did above caused it to work when it didnt initially..