# How to install the latest version of Blender in Ubuntu, instead of the old version in the official repositories?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation, uninstall, blender

I'm new to blender, was trying to render my project, and ran into a [bug](https://developer.blender.org/T82499) that appears to be a problem with the blender installed by `sudo apt install blender`.

Fortunately, the blender website has a more recent version that doesn't have the bug, version 2.92.0. I downloaded the **blender-2.92.0-linux64.tar.xz** file from their website and extracted it in my home directory and you can run it right from that location. I would like to remove the *Blender 2.82 (sub 7)* installed by apt and make my system refer to the blender i've downloaded myself such that command line uses the new version. Right now this refers to the old version:

```bsh
$ blender -v
Blender 2.82 (sub 7)
```

So my questions are:

1. to remove the old blender (and any vestige of its files), is it sufficient to just `sudo apt remove blender`?
2. where in my file system should I put the contents of **blender-2.92.0-linux64.tar.xz**? Is there a standard location for software that you install yourself?
3. Are there any environment variables I need to set? Should I set these in .profile? .bashrc? Or somewhere else?
4. Do I need to create any kind of symbolic link in /usr/bin directory or something like that to point to the new version of blender?

**EDIT:** some additional information.

Extracting the tar file yields these contents:

```
$ ls -l blender-2.92.0-linux64
total 238960
drwxrwxr-x 5 jaith jaith      4096 Apr 14 19:56 2.92
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jaith jaith 244635248 Feb 25 01:33 blender
-rw-r--r-- 1 jaith jaith      5589 Jan 13 08:40 blender.desktop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jaith jaith       713 Jan 13 08:40 blender-softwaregl
-rw-r--r-- 1 jaith jaith      1732 Jan 13 08:40 blender.svg
-rw-r--r-- 1 jaith jaith      3874 Jan 13 08:40 blender-symbolic.svg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jaith jaith      5340 Jan 13 08:40 blender-thumbnailer.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jaith jaith      4765 Jan 13 08:40 copyright.txt
drwxrwxr-x 2 jaith jaith      4096 Apr 14 19:56 lib
drwxrwxr-x 2 jaith jaith      4096 Apr 14 19:56 license
-rw-r--r-- 1 jaith jaith      5200 Feb 25 01:31 readme.html
```

There's the **blender** executable, the **blender.desktop** file, with these two entries of special interest because they have no path whatsoever:

```
Exec=blender %f
Icon=blender
```

I believe a proper installation should not require any changes to PATH so I think the answer to my question #3 should probably be **NO**. Path on my machine is currently:

```bsh
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

which does not include `/use/share/applications` (or `/usr/share/applications`).

**EDIT 2:** I would add that the information in the readme.html file that comes with Blender is especially unhelpful:

> **INSTALLATION**
> Linux: Unpack the archive, then run the Blender executable.

The [linux install instructions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/getting_started/installing/linux.html) on the Blender site also look rather unorthodox and incomplete as well.

Comment: There must be a binary executable file in it. The desktop file must have the full path of that. You can place it under `/use/share/applications` for all users to access. But I suggest you to go with the PPA instead. It would give you automatic updates, but is not a large download like snap/flatpak. And it would take care of placing files properly.

Comment: Can you run `ls` on the extracted directory and post the output? (it gives list of all files). I cannot tell you the exact filename without examining what all files are there.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I have added the list of files as well as some other detail.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the details. However, you can use the other installation methods (ppa/snap/flatpak/appimage), they are much more simpler.

Answer (score 9):

**Short answer** - *If you are confused by so many options, simply add the PPA (described below) with the following commands, and everything will be automatically taken care of.*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/blender
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blender
```

### Long answer

---

---

### To remove apt version of blender

---

Use the command

```
sudo apt purge blender
```

to remove blender and all its configuration files. Then, you can also run

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

to remove the unused dependencies of blender (and also of other apps).

### To install the latest version of blender

---

- Extract the .tar.gz file in your home folder. Rename the new directory to `blender`. Edit the `Exec` entry of `blender.desktop` to `Exec=/home/your-username/blender/blender %f`, and the `Icon` entry to `Icon=/home/your-username/blender/blender.svg`.

Then place the .desktop file in `.local/share/applications` in your home folder, so that it can be searched in the menu. Alternatively, you can also place it in `/usr/share/applications` (you will need to have sudo access to do that), if you want all users to access it.

To call `blender` from command line, you can either copy the `blender` binary file in the extracted folder, or create a symbolic link to it, at `/usr/local/bin/blender`.

To create a symbolic link, run the command `sudo ln -s /home/your-username/blender/blender /usr/local/bin/blender`

***You can also place the extracted folder to any other location of your choice. Then you would have to edit the .desktop file accordingly.***

- If you prefer traditional package, you can use the unofficial [Blender PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Esavoury1/+archive/ubuntu/blender) instead.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/blender
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blender
```

- You can also use the [Appimage](https://www.appimagehub.com/p/1169218/) instead. Download (it is a single file) and double click to run.
- You can also use the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/blender) or [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.blender.Blender) versions

```
sudo snap install blender
```

or

```
flatpak install flathub org.blender.Blender
```

- There is no need to set any environment variable or symbolic links. If you use the `blender-x.tar.gz`, you can simply create a .desktop file and save it in `.local/share/applications`. If you use the PPA, appimage, or snap or flatpak, that would be taken care of automatically.

Comment: this is a helpful answer. Where should I put the contents of the downloaded **blender.tar.xz** file? It's currently just in a temporary location.

Comment: your answer is helpful, but incomplete. The blender.tar.xz has quite a few files in it, and should probably live in a **blender** folder somewhere (/opt? /usr/local/share? /usr/local/lib?). This blender tar archive also already contains a blender.desktop file but that file simple assigns no path in the Exec section, with only `Exec=blender %f`. Sounds like we will need to either edit the PATH or put a symbolic link in one of the directories already in the path like /usr/local/bin. Also, if I'm not mistaken, .local would be only for a single user. I'd like it to be for all.

Comment: In large part where to put binaries is up to you. It doesn't matter which folder, other users can use it if they have permissions. I'd do `which blender` before purging (which will remove config files!), then put the new blender binary in the old location. Yes .desktop files may need modifying and placing; this is why people stick with packages.

Comment: _"... or create a symbolic link to it, at `/usr/bin/blender`."_ - Please use `/usr/local/bin/` for that. `/usr/bin/` is under control of the package manager, the `/usr/local/` is [intended](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html) for locally-installed software. This provides a cleaner separation between apt-managed software and manually installed software, easing among other things cleanup later.

Comment: @marcelm Done. Thanks.

Comment: to create the link: `sudo ln -s /home/your-username/blender/blender /usr/local/bin/blender`