# ubuntu-drivers "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment" when installing nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, ubuntu-drivers

I am running into trouble reinstalling my nvidia drivers after the latest kernel upgrade.  Normally, ubuntu-drivers handles it, but not this time.

I've done `sudo apt purge -y nvidia-*`, which often fixes problems when reinstalling, but that didn't help.

When I run `ubuntu-drivers install`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 513, in <module>
    greet()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 413, in install
    command_install(config)
  File "/usr/bin/ubuntu-drivers", line 187, in command_install
    UbuntuDrivers.detect.nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook(to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment
```

Is the with_nvidia_kms message at the bottom related at all to DKMS?  I had numerous problems in the past getting dkms to work in the past, before switching to ubuntu-drivers.

This was all working until a recent upgrade, which involved a kernel.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1993019

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This relates to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1993019) that has been fixed, it should be solved by upgrading the `ubuntu-drivers-common` package.

```
sudo apt install --only-upgrade ubuntu-drivers-common
```

Otherwise, the manual solution consists in editing the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py`" file and replace line 835 with:

```
version = int(package_name.split('-')[-2])
```

The only change I'm bringing is -2 instead of -1. Otherwise it raises a ValueError inside the try block and just doesn't give any value to the version variable.

Comment: Thanks for this precise fix. Changed here from -1 to -2 and it worked (Ubuntu 22.04): `sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia`

Comment: A safer approach may be keeping it inside another `try` block inside `except ValueError:` block.

Comment: this also worked for me with ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: +1 working for me as well as of this writing. Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Or you may just avoid the nvidia drivers with names ending in "-open".  Some scripts are looking for a version as the last thing in the name.

Comment: A fix has been released (as stated in the link in the answer). updating via the Software Updater GUI solved this for me.

Comment: If version has something like `-server-open`, then we need change it to `version = int(package_name.split('-')[-3])`

Answer (score 0):

There was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1993019) for which a fix has now been released. You can upgrade the Ubuntu driver package with:

```
sudo apt install --only-upgrade ubuntu-drivers-common
```